# How to import your example files into my Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I believe many of you have ADF experiences, and may be have seen Mark Kromer's example of azure data flows (https://github.com/kromerm/adfdataflowdocs)

I am a beginner using ADF and azure Data Flows especially. I am very curious of these examples, and I really want to import all your examples files (json) to my newly created data factory. It must be an easier way than creating all activities, connections, datasets and others manually. The templates are of course good but I want to test out your example code in my azure portal and in my data factory.

And just a second question: I am a SSIS man used control flows with master packages executing other packages. When I am now building a data warehouse in ADF with many dimension tables and fact tables, is it best practice to have separate data flows or should I build general data flows that either have many parallel upserts to different dimensions? I think I need some guiding here

Thank you

Regards Geir

Answer (score 0):

I've been publishing those example data flows as ADF pipeline templates.

In your browser, go to ADF and then click Factory Resources > Pipeline from Template. You should see a Data Flow category. Many of the examples are in there.

In ADF, you can also have master / child packages. You'll use Execute Pipeline in ADF instead of execute package.

ADF supports re-use and generalization of data flow patterns, so that you could process multiple dimension tables in a single data flow. You'll have to weigh the value of doing that vs. supporting it long-term as well as the danger of creating a very complex data flow.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Amazing work you have done and thanks for your fast responding